# CodeIgniter routes not working with subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, subdomain

I have CodeIgniter application that I transferred to a subdomain: customer.domain.com/application-name/

Now when I access the above URL, I can see the login page and links to images etc. work.

What doesn't work, however, is routing. It returns a 500 server error because what it tries to do is access:

```
customer.domain.com/customer/class/method
```

So as you can see, somehow the subdomain is appended to the  url. This should not be the case. The configured base path should be used. So I would expect it to access:

```
customer.domain.com/application-name/class/method
```

.

I have the feeling I need to add something in my .htaccess file, but I'm not quite sure what to do.

My config.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pub";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['welcome'] = 'pub/welcome';
$route['send_new'] = 'pub/send_new';
$route['cron'] = 'pub/cron';
$route['invitation/(:any)'] = 'pub/invitation/$1';
$route['unsubscribe/(:any)'] = 'pub/unsubscribe/$1';
$route['widget/(:any)'] = 'pub/widget/$1';
$route['excel-tpl'] = 'pub/excel_tpl';
$route['pub/(:any)'] = 'pub/$1';
$route['pub/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pub/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pub/short_url/$1';
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(js|css)$ - [L]

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f 
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d 
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: check the value of $config['base_url'] in application/config/config.php & make sure it's correct.

Comment: It is: 'http://customer.domain.com/application-name/' So that should not be the issue.

Comment: baseurl should start with http or https ... or you can try leaving it empty & see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried both. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(js|css)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^customer\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://customer.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f 
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d 
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

to `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: You posted `routes.php`, not `config.php` file. Pay attention on precedence. `pub/(:any)/(:any)` has to be before `pub/(:any)`.